# Service Layer inject multiple DAO in practice

Tags: java, spring, architecture

Here is a design problem between Dao layer and Service Layer:

In DAO layer, there are DAO Classes called:
Dao1, Dao2, Dao3 ...

In Service Layer, there are Service Classes called:
Service1, Service2, Service3 ...

Service1 need to inject Dao1, Dao2, Dao3

Service2 need to inject Dao2, Dao3, Dao4

Service3 need to inject Dao3

...

Example for creating a user:

UserService need to inject UserDao to create user, Also UserService need to inject LogDao
to record system log information.

It seems there are some repeating work we need to do. Is there any solution in practice? I 
am using Spring framework. Using @Resource annotation to inject these Dao in Service Class.

My solution is:
inject all the Dao Class (Dao1, Dao2, Dao3 ...) into DaoCollection Class, then service1, service2, service3... all extends DaoCollection Class. Is it good approach?

Thx

Comment: I don't understand if the DAO and service classes have any relation to each other, if the DAOs are for different aspects or what. Could you explain the context and purpose of this construct a bit more?

Comment: @leet3lite Sorry for my explanation. I have added some example. Hope it could help. thank you for ur time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to define the DAOs that your services use anyway, so you'd have to do that 'repeating' work to some extend.

Depending on the framework you use (if any) that declaration shouldn't be too much overhead (to type).

Example in EJB 3+:

```
class Service1 {
  @EJB private DAO1 dao1;
  @EJB private DAO2 dao2;
  @EJB private DAO3 dao3;
  ...
}
```

I'd say you shouldn't create a common superclass and inject all possible DAOs there. This will most likely make it harder to understand (why are those DAOs there?, are they used?, etc.) and might even have performance issues, depending on the framework in use (you might inject every DAO into each service and thus create a big pool of unused DAO instances).

Comment: +1. I'd also like to add that creating a DAOCollection and extending it with the services means inheritance whereas the IoC is all about object composition, so the idea kind of defeats the purpose.